# Capybara: fill_in action locator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

So I have this spec

```
describe "visit /signup" do
    before(:each) do
        get signup_path
    end
    it "has an email input field" do
        page.has_field?("#user_email")
    end
    it "accepts an email address" do
        page.fill_in('#user_email', :with=>Faker::Internet.email)
    end
end
```

The first test (has an email input) passes, the second fails with

```
Failure/Error: page.fill_in('#user_email', :with=>Faker::Internet.email)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label '#user_email' found
```

The input[type='text'] element exists on the page with that DOM ID, have tried locating with the ID with and without the hash, and using its input:name as a locator too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `save_and_open_page` was super useful in debugging too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using `get` when you should be using `visit` inside the `before` block. This:

```
before(:each) do
  get signup_path
end
```

Should be this:

```
before(:each) do
    visit signup_path
end
```

Otherwise you're telling `Rack::Test` to visit that path, *not* Capybara! A small distinction that trips quite a few people up frequently!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should remove the `#`, e.g.

```
fill_in('user_email', :with=>Faker::Internet.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fill_in is not on page. Just use fill_in:

```
describe "visit /signup" do
    before(:each) do
        get signup_path
    end
    it "has an email input field" do
        page.has_field?("#user_email")
    end
    it "accepts an email address" do
        fill_in('#user_email', :with=>Faker::Internet.email)
    end
end
```